Generative models - valid distribution requirement
In "Deep learning" by Bishop there is a requirement for generative models that looks wrong to me

(Equation 14.49, page 452, online at https://www.bishopbook.com/ )
I think it should only require p(x|w) to integrate to 1 over x. Is there an error in the book or what am I missing?
My justification for doubting the equation: if you consider a uniform distribution p(x) over [0, 2], the equation doesn’t hold even if p(x|w) matches p(x).
(I already asked on Data Science StackExchange and one of the comments suggested trying a stats related community)

Having looked at the text, I think it's an error in the book.

Might be worth emailing Bishop as I'm sure he's collecting errata from the book.

I have emailed feedback@bishopbook.com already

Since here $p(x|w)$ is explicitly defined as conditional probability distribution, you're right it's a typo here and we can only derive its normalization as $\int p(x|w)dx = 1$ and the marginal evidence as $p(x) = \int p(x,w)dw = \int p(x|w)p(w)dw$.
